# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated within embedded Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have scripted a simple Ajax function and embedded this to my website.

On the console I get this warning

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

What does this mean and how to avoid it?

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var allText = "";
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
    return allText;
}

function load() {
    var allText = readTextFile('drinks.json');
    var mydata = JSON.parse(allText);
    var div = document.getElementById('cocktaillist');

    div.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<p class='inner' id="+i+">"+ mydata[i].name +"</p>" + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code to use asynchronous Ajax requests. As the warning indicates, using synchronous requests is bad for the user experience. Also, there literally *never* is a reason to use synchronous Ajax requests, ever.

And that means you need to use callback functions. Compare:

```
function getText(path, success) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", path, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                success(req.responseText);       // call a function with the received value
            } else {
                console.log("unexpected response status " + req.status);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
}

function load() {
    getText('drinks.json', function (allText) {  // pass a function to call when the request is done
        var mydata = JSON.parse(allText);
        var div = document.getElementById('cocktaillist');
        div.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<p class='inner' id="+i+">"+ mydata[i].name +"</p>" + "<br>";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you observed:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
> its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Is a warning about the fact that a synchronous request defeats the asynchronous nature of JavaScript and blocks the user interface, which causes bad user experience, especially in case of bad network quality.

You should set `true` as third parameter of `rawFile.open()` and you already provided a `rawFile.onreadystatechange` callback in order to execute code when you have received a response, so the rest of your code is fine.

Comment: But with true, the data is not loaded and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" because allText is empty

Comment: In asynchronous mode, the `return allText` actually executes **before** the `rawFile.onreadystatechange` callback function. All your code that uses `allText` should go inside the `rawFile.onreadystatechange` callback.